# Drupal 7 push notification . Error when sending push to ios devices

Tags: ios, drupal, drupal-7

I have an issue when trying to send push to ios devices.
    Warning: stream_socket_client(): Unable to set private key file 
sites/all/modules/push_notifications/certificates/apns-production-48d49d3853.pem' in     push_notifications_apns_feedback_service().

Help,please.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the **certificate file** for push notification, and then you need to **rename** it to "**apns-production-48d49d3853.pem**" to put into 
**[you-site]/modules/push_notifications/certificates/**  folder